# Errors while processing: python3-apt,usb-creator,apport,python-apt

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, python, dpkg

I'm not an advanced user of Ubuntu, and I have a really big issue.
When I run:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I get the following output:

```
Hit:1 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease                  
Hit:3 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease                
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu bionic InRelease         
Ign:5 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/manuelschneid3r/xUbuntu_18.04  InRelease
Hit:6 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/manuelschneid3r/xUbuntu_18.04  Release
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/team-xbmc/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease                
Hit:8 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic InRelease                     
Hit:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease                   
Hit:11 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie InRelease      
Reading package lists... Done                                  
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  linux-generic-hwe-18.04 linux-headers-generic-hwe-18.04
  linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
6 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up python3-apt (1.6.4) ...
/bin/sh: 1: /usr/bin/python3.6: Permission denied
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3compile", line 290, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3compile", line 270, in main
    options.force, options.optimize, e_patterns)
  File "/usr/bin/py3compile", line 156, in compile
    cfn = interpreter.cache_file(fn, version)
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/interpreter.py", line 212, in cache_file
    (fname[:-3], self.magic_tag(version), last_char))
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/interpreter.py", line 246, in magic_tag
    return self._execute('import imp; print(imp.get_tag())', version)
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/interpreter.py", line 359, in _execute
    raise Exception('{} failed with status code {}'.format(command, output['returncode']))
Exception: python3.6 -c 'import imp; print(imp.get_tag())' failed with status code 126
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 24, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3compile", line 290, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3compile", line 270, in main
    options.force, options.optimize, e_patterns)
  File "/usr/bin/py3compile", line 156, in compile
    cfn = interpreter.cache_file(fn, version)
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/interpreter.py", line 212, in cache_file
    (fname[:-3], self.magic_tag(version), last_char))
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/interpreter.py", line 246, in magic_tag
    return self._execute('import imp; print(imp.get_tag())', version)
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/interpreter.py", line 359, in _execute
    raise Exception('{} failed with status code {}'.format(command, output['returncode']))
Exception: python3.6 -c 'import imp; print(imp.get_tag())' failed with status code 126
dpkg: error processing package python3-apt (--configure):
 installed python3-apt package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Setting up usb-creator-common (0.3.5ubuntu18.04.2) ...
/bin/sh: 1: /usr/bin/python3.6: Permission denied
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3compile", line 290, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3compile", line 270, in main
    options.force, options.optimize, e_patterns)
  File "/usr/bin/py3compile", line 156, in compile
    cfn = interpreter.cache_file(fn, version)
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/interpreter.py", line 212, in cache_file
    (fname[:-3], self.magic_tag(version), last_char))
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/interpreter.py", line 246, in magic_tag
    return self._execute('import imp; print(imp.get_tag())', version)
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/interpreter.py", line 359, in _execute
    raise Exception('{} failed with status code {}'.format(command, output['returncode']))
Exception: python3.6 -c 'import imp; print(imp.get_tag())' failed with status code 126
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 24, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3compile", line 290, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3compile", line 270, in main
    options.force, options.optimize, e_patterns)
  File "/usr/bin/py3compile", line 156, in compile
    cfn = interpreter.cache_file(fn, version)
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/interpreter.py", line 212, in cache_file
    (fname[:-3], self.magic_tag(version), last_char))
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/interpreter.py", line 246, in magic_tag
    return self._execute('import imp; print(imp.get_tag())', version)
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/interpreter.py", line 359, in _execute
    raise Exception('{} failed with status code {}'.format(command, output['returncode']))
Exception: python3.6 -c 'import imp; print(imp.get_tag())' failed with status code 126
dpkg: error processing package usb-creator-common (--configure):
 installed usb-creator-common package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of usb-creator-gtk:
 usb-creator-gtk depends on usb-creator-common (= 0.3.5ubuntu18.04.2); however:
  Package usb-creator-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package usb-creator-gtk (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                     dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-apport:
 python3-apport depends on python3-apt (>= 0.7.9); however:
  Package python3-apt is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-apport (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of apport:
 apport depends on python3-apport (>= 2.20.9-0ubuntu7.7); however:
  Package python3-apport is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package apport (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                       Setting up python-apt (1.6.4) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-apt.postinst: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python-apt.postinst: pycompile: Permission denied
dpkg: error processing package python-apt (--configure):
 installed python-apt package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 126
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3-apt
 usb-creator-common
 usb-creator-gtk
 python3-apport
 apport
 python-apt
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried many different solutions from this site, but nothing works for me. Something went wrong when I tried to update Python from 3.6 to 3.7. I'm sorry if I am talking about a topic that already exists, but I can't find any solution that works with all these errors combined. I can add any command output you want, but, as I said, I'm not a very advanced user.

---

@nobody

Input:

```
sudo dpkg -i python3-apt_1.6.0_amd64.deb python-apt_1.6.0_amd64.deb
```

Output:

```
dpkg: warning: downgrading python3-apt from 1.6.4 to 1.6.0
(Reading database ... 182414 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack python3-apt_1.6.0_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python3-apt (1.6.0) over (1.6.4) ...
Preparing to unpack python-apt_1.6.0_amd64.deb ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-apt.prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python-apt.prerm: pyclean: Permission denied
dpkg: error processing archive python-apt_1.6.0_amd64.deb (--install):
 installed python-apt package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 126
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-apt.postinst: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python-apt.postinst: pycompile: Permission denied
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 installed python-apt package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 126
Setting up python3-apt (1.6.0) ...
/bin/sh: 1: /usr/bin/python3.6: Permission denied
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3compile", line 290, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3compile", line 270, in main
    options.force, options.optimize, e_patterns)
  File "/usr/bin/py3compile", line 156, in compile
    cfn = interpreter.cache_file(fn, version)
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/interpreter.py", line 212, in cache_file
    (fname[:-3], self.magic_tag(version), last_char))
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/interpreter.py", line 246, in magic_tag
    return self._execute('import imp; print(imp.get_tag())', version)
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/interpreter.py", line 359, in _execute
    raise Exception('{} failed with status code {}'.format(command, output['returncode']))
Exception: python3.6 -c 'import imp; print(imp.get_tag())' failed with status code 126
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 24, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3compile", line 290, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3compile", line 270, in main
    options.force, options.optimize, e_patterns)
  File "/usr/bin/py3compile", line 156, in compile
    cfn = interpreter.cache_file(fn, version)
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/interpreter.py", line 212, in cache_file
    (fname[:-3], self.magic_tag(version), last_char))
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/interpreter.py", line 246, in magic_tag
    return self._execute('import imp; print(imp.get_tag())', version)
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/interpreter.py", line 359, in _execute
    raise Exception('{} failed with status code {}'.format(command, output['returncode']))
Exception: python3.6 -c 'import imp; print(imp.get_tag())' failed with status code 126
dpkg: error processing package python3-apt (--install):
 installed python3-apt package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-apt_1.6.0_amd64.deb
 python3-apt
```

I hope that system reinstallation isn't one and only way to fix it

Comment: Try `sudo apt install -f` then do your update and upgrade

Comment: Exactly how did you try to migrate from Py3.6 to Py3.7? If you followed online instructions, a link would be very helpful. How you fix the problem depends upon how you created the problem. Alternately, if possible, revert to py3.6. Depending upon the method you followed, it might be as simple ad changing one symlink.

Comment: @user535733 
http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/07/install-python-3-6-1-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts/ but I think when I tried to fix it, I broke it even more

Comment: @singrium 
The same error

Comment: Try running `sudo apt install --reinstall python3-apt`

Comment: Looks can restore 3.6 functionality (including apt) by simpoly following those instructions again, pointing everything back to 3.6. Then your package manager should work.

Comment: @user3140225
`Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
6 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
E: Internal Error, No file name for python3-apt:amd64
e for python3-apt:amd64`

Answer (score 0):

Internal Error sounds not good.

```
wget -c http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python-apt/python3-apt_1.6.0_amd64.deb
```

and

```
wget -c http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python-apt/python-apt_1.6.0_amd64.deb
```

Install the 2 package with `sudo dpkg -i python3-apt_1.6.0_amd64.deb python-apt_1.6.0_amd64.deb`

If this work `sudo dpkg --configure -a && sudo apt -f install`

Then upgdrade your system

```
sudo apt full-upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on Ubuntu 22.04 with python 3.10.4. The following command resolved the issue:

`sudo apt --fix-broken install`